# Tracker list indices must be str

Tags: python

Okay I am trying to get the people and timestamp in a tracker but I keep getting this error:

```
list indices must be integer, not str
```

This is the code that gets that error:

```
elif used_prefix and cmd == "tracker" and self.getAccess(user) >= 1:
   try:
     if len(args) == 0:
        name = user.name.lower()
    elif len(args) > 0:
        name = args.lower()
    f = urlreq.urlopen("http://chtracker.info/index.py?output=json&x=page&y={}".format(name))
    data = json.loads(f.readall().decode("utf-8"))['viewer'][:10]
    t = "{}, the last 10 people who visited {}'s profile are: ".format(name.title(), name.title())
    viewers = [(item['viewer'], item['timestamp']) for item in data]
    for l in viewers:
       viewer, timest = l
       t += "{} about {} ago".format(viewer, stamp.getTimeStamp((timest)))
   room.message(t, True)
except:
   print(traceback.format_exc())
   room.message((str(sys.exc_info()[1])))
```

The error happens on this line:

```
data = json.loads(f.readall().decode('utf-8'))['viewer'][:10]
```

Inside the url are dictionarys with the same tags "viewer" and "timestamp" for example:

```
http://chtracker.info/index.py?output=json&x=page&y=mechabot
```

Comment: I reverted the question to the original one, since it was clearly a substantial change invalidating existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

`json.loads(...)` is returning a `list` so when you do:

```
json.loads(...)['viewer']
```

you are trying to access to a `list` with the index `'viewer'` which is not valid.

You could realize this by printing `json.loads(f.readall().decode("utf-8"))` so you figure out the right way of accessing it's values.

Comment: Okay I fixed that but now I'm getting a invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: Could you post the value of `data`? It seems like you are trying to cast to `int` a invalid value.

Comment: @user3103923 Don't edit to change the question. Ask a new one, or just ask Christian for this issue. Leave the original problem there.